# Mongodb datatime query failed

Tags: mongodb

I've got a problem with the query:

```
queryInactive: { "lastActivityTime" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2011-03-09T04:19:03Z"}}}
```

This is printed by morphia `toString()`

There are a lot of documents whose last activity time is less than this datetime, but no one has been found by this query.

What's the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess from the information you have included, but I would guess that your data types are inconsistent. Can you check that the dates stored in mongodb are not strings.

If all the information was created by morphia (and the java driver) then you should not have this problem, but other drivers/languages are not so careful.

I would also suggest posting on the morphia list to get help. Please include your code example for the query, how the data is saved, and sample data from the shell: http://groups.google.com/group/morphia

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "lastActivityTime" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : new Date(2011,2,9,4,19,3)}}}
```

The type is not string。

You can see Javascript's date type。

In morphia。

```
.filter("createdate >=", date)//The date type is not String.It's date type.
```